# Div Fixa com Efeito FadeIn

Tags: javascript, css

Opa,

Tenho uma div na lateral `sidebar_right`, ao rolar a página ela deve ir para o rodapé fixa, estou usando assim:

```
    $(function () {

    var jElement = $('#sidebar_right');

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 700 )
        {
            jElement.fadeIn(500);
            jElement.css({
                'position':'fixed',
                'top':'60%',
                'z-index':'999',
                'width':'100%',
                'left':'0',
                'overflow':'scroll',
                'height':'300px',
            });

        }else{

            //jElement.fadeOut(500); Não usado

            jElement.css({
                'position':'relative',
                'top':'auto',
                'overflow':'hidden',
                'height':'auto',
                'z-index':'999',
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Funciona normalmente, mas, sem o efeito `fadein`, o `fadein` só ocorre quando adiciono o `fadeout`, lá no `else`. Não posso adicionar o `fadeout`, pois, é a mesma div.

O que  há de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Nao tem como voce aplicar o efeito `fadeIn` em um elemento visivel, ele serve para "mostrar" um elemento invisivel(`display:none` ou `opacity:0`) com o efeito de `fade`(aumentando a opacidade do elemento). Para ter o efeito que você deseja esconda o elemento antes de chamar o `fadeIn`:

```
var jElement = $('#sidebar_right');

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 700 )
    {
        jElement.hide(0); // esconde o elemento
        jElement.fadeIn(500);
        jElement.css({
            'position':'fixed',
            'top':'60%',
            'z-index':'999',
            'width':'100%',
            'left':'0',
            'overflow':'scroll',
            'height':'300px',
        });

    }else{

        jElement.css({
            'position':'relative',
            'top':'auto',
            'overflow':'hidden',
            'height':'auto',
            'z-index':'999',
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Opa amigão, adicionei o `jElement.hide(0);`, ao mover o scrool a div desaparece e reaparece diversas vezes

Comment: Será que é possível adicionar um tipo de fade no css ao descer o scrool ?

Comment: Teria uma pagina de testes para mim ver. O fade ate tem em css ja o scroll nunca vi.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz o seguinte:

```
#sidebar_bottom
{
    position:fixed;
    top:60%;
    z-index:999;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    overflow:scroll;
    height:300px;
}





    var jElement_right  = $('#sidebar_right');
    var jElement_bottom = $('#sidebar_bottom');

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 700 )
        {
            jElement_right.fadeOut(500);
            jElement_bottom.fadeIn(500);

        }else{
            jElement_bottom.fadeOut(500);
            jElement_right.fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
```

Ou seja, adicionei o arquivo.php com um include em divs diferentes, ao descer a tela uma div apaga e a outra aparece fixada no rodape.

Funcionando perfeitamente.

Vlw